# R as.Date() has two different return fomats

Tags: r

Here is my observation. Given this sample data

```
> xx
     [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]      
[1,] "ABC" "20" "04" "13" "C"  "00700000"
[2,] "XYZ" "20" "04" "13" "C"  "00800000"
> class(xx)
[1] "matrix"
```

I wrote a simple function to parse this data matrix:

```
foo <- function(xx)
{ 
   year=2000+as.integer(xx[2])
   month = as.integer(xx[3])
   day=as.integer(xx[4])
   as.Date(sprintf("%02d-%02d-%04d",month,day, year), format="%m-%d-%Y")
}
```

When applying this function to xx using apply(), I got these:

```
> apply(xx, 1, foo)
[1] 18365 18365
```

I don't know why 18365 was displayed here, maybe 18365 representing NA? Some posts on Stack Overflow said as.Date is sensitive to Sys.setlocale(). But if I just type this in the same terminal:

```
> as.Date(sprintf("%02d-%02d-%04d", 4, 23, 2020), format="%m-%d-%Y")
[1] "2020-04-23"
```

So it seems proved there is no Sys.setlocale() problem for as.Date(). Can someone point out what the problem is? Thanks
So it proved

Comment: a "Date" object is just an integer with a special print method `as.integer(as.Date("2020-04-23"))`

Answer (score 0):

`apply` will do that.  See the reference to `as.vector` in the help file for `apply`.

**1)** Instead, use `ISOdate` and `as.Date`.

```
as.Date(ISOdate(as.integer(m[, 2]) + 2000L, m[, 3], m[, 4]))
## [1] "2020-04-13" "2020-04-13"
```

**2)** or `as.Date` and `paste`:

```
as.Date(paste(as.integer(m[, 2]) + 2000L, m[, 3], m[, 4], sep = "-"))
## [1] "2020-04-13" "2020-04-13"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- '"ABC" "20" "04" "13" "C"  "00700000"
"XYZ" "20" "04" "13" "C"  "00800000"'
m <- matrix(scan(text = Lines, what = "", quiet = TRUE), 2, byrow = TRUE)

m
##      [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]      
## [1,] "ABC" "20" "04" "13" "C"  "00700000"
## [2,] "XYZ" "20" "04" "13" "C"  "00800000"
```

Comment: right, your solution produced exactly like the way you showed. But can post post your solution using apply()? I used the as.Date with paste, I still got the same answer. Looks like it is about the apply()? i want to understand why there are different returns. thanks!

Comment: Did you read the first two sentences and follow up???